# Not getting database table updated

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am simply writing an `INSERT` query to insert values into the table, when I click the `submit` button the code runs successfully, I don't get any error.

But when I look into the table it shows no data i.e the table is not updated. I don't know why it's happening. Can anyone suggest me.

thank you

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the query. Does it say how many rows that are affected? Have you a where condition that does not match any data? Have you refreshed the table select view after the insert?

Comment: Forgot to commit transaction ?

Comment: Maybe it does generate an error but you aren't looking at it's return value?

Comment: I agree with @gor. Query runs and no exception, but no update usually points to transaction not committed.

Comment: @manisha
: please post your code...

Comment: without any code, its impossible to know what is going on

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem if you are using c# windows application probably you have two different data base connection one updated and another still not updated so check your connections and if you are using sql express your database might be replicated in you debug directory so check your debuge folder or run your application from executable file.